# How to use input variables with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm currently working on a Python script where I'd like to have general options. That is because the ultimate goal is to output a URL that has parameters, and each parameter corresponds to an input variable. So maybe the URL has the username parameter, or the date parameter, or the domain parameter, etc. If a user wants to input a username, they can type something like:

```
script.py -u johndoe
```

Then the script would take the part after `-u`, equal it to the variable `username`, and then insert it into the URL at the appropriate place.

How can I do something like this? I tried doing something with this code, but I don't know where to start, how can I use input variables alongside argparse.

```
import argparse

parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', action='N', type=str, nargs='+',
                    help='What's the username?')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: `N` is not a valid action, and why would you use `nargs='+'` for an option that takes a single argument?

Comment: You need to escape the `'` inside `what's the username?`

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know how to get the information out of the parsed arguments (which is in the argparse documentation)? Or are you stuck at something else?

Comment: I'm stuck at taking the username the user typed and inserting it into the URL. So say I have a URL like https://facebook.com/username, I want when the user types `-u alextrebek` to turn into https://facebook.com/alextrebek, you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. If the username is not pass as argument the args.username will be `None`. If the username is mandatory, you should pass `required=True` to add_argument(...) call.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description="My script")
parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', type=str, 
                    help="What's the username?", required=False)

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.username)
```

Comment: Since the question states "So maybe the URL has the username parameter", I don't think the username is mandatory.

Comment: @9769953, fixed the code and the comment, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much, you guys are amazing, I just learned something new today!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you want to know how to use the arguments in your program. You can get them by converting them to a dictonary.

```
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
username = args['username']
```

So your whole code should look something like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-u','--username', help='Some help', required=True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
username = args['username']

print(username)
```

Comment: That's not an array; that is a dictionary.

Comment: Also, why not simply use the attributes as such? `username = args.username`?

Comment: @9769953 Thanks, I edited it. I always used dictonaries in the past, but attributes look also like a nice way.

Comment: Appreciate your help! My god, it's really clear. Dictionaries are awesome! So much flexibility.